# How to obtain the pixel coordinates of a QR code recognized by the Windows UWP ClaimedBarcodeScanner

Tags: c#, uwp, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I'm building a Windows UWP app that includes a QR code scanner based on a built-in camera of the device that is running the app. There is a [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BarcodeScanner) that explains how to do this hosted on GitHub.

So far, my scanner is running properly and I'm able to extract the information contained within QR codes. The sample does a decent job explaining how to do that.

However, as a next step I would like to be able to draw a shape around the recognized QR code. To be able to do so I'd need to obtain the pixel coordinates of the recognized QR code.

If a QR code is recognized the `ClaimedBarcodeScanner.DataReceived` event gets [fired](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice.claimedbarcodescanner.datareceived). The callback then receives a  BarcodeScannerDataReceivedEventArgs which in terms contains a [BarcodeScannerReport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice.barcodescannerreport) object. This object has the three properties [ScanData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice.barcodescannerreport.scandata#Windows_Devices_PointOfService_BarcodeScannerReport_ScanData), [ScanDataLabel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice.barcodescannerreport.scandatalabel#Windows_Devices_PointOfService_BarcodeScannerReport_ScanDataLabel) and [ScanDataType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice.barcodescannerreport.scandatatype#Windows_Devices_PointOfService_BarcodeScannerReport_ScanDataType).

I suspect that the coordinates *might* be stored in the `ScanData` property but this is essentially a junk of raw data and neither the documentation nor the sample code explain in what format data is stored within that property.

There is a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/winrt-api/issues/437) open that requests clarification in the documentation but that issue has been opened around 10 months ago and nothing has happened.

Does anyone have an idea whether the barcode scanner reveals the pixel coordinates and if so, how to access those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, as a next step I would like to be able to draw a shape around the recognized QR code. To be able to do so I'd need to obtain the pixel coordinates of the recognized QR code.

You could get [`ScanData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-barcodescanner-scan-data#get-the-data)(**The full, raw barcode data**) with `BarcodeScannerDataReceivedEventArgs`. And it contain **Timing Pattern** that used to correct the center coordinates in the unit when the QR code appears distorted. And this data is security.

Your requirement is **draw a shape around the recognized QR code**, in other words, you want to realize QR image recognition feature. **Timing Pattern** only record the center coordinates of each cell in the QR code, it could not be use to identify the coordinates of the QR code edge in the preview.

Currently, UWP has not provide such api for drawing a shape around the recognized QR code. if you do want this feature please feel free post your requirement on the [**UserVoice**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform)

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thanks for you answer, I'll open a corresponding request.

Comment: For reference, here's the link to the feature request I logged: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/37699078-provide-pixel-coordinates-of-barcodes-recognized-b